# Unable to edit the Excel file from SharePoint 2010

Tags: excel, sharepoint

There is an Excel file in my SharePoint library and when i open it it opens in a read only mode and when i click on edit it says that

**"The http://URL of the site.xslx the file or folder name contains invalid characters that does not exist. Enter a different name."

There are no special characters..

Comment: The error message looks quite garbled. Are you sure this is the *exact* message you received? Is the message coming from the browser or Excel? Do you already have the file opened in Excel or in the browser when you receive that message?

Comment: I Clicked on Open of the Excel file from the SharePoint library and it got opened in the read mode and now when i try to edit it then i am getting the error that "<SharePoint site URL with excel file>" folder name contains invalid characters that does not exist. Enter a different name."

Comment: By "read mode" do you mean that it opens in Internet Explorer or in Excel? What is the full URL to the Excel file? SharePoint is not just picky about special characters but also about certain words and characters at the beginning or end of your folder and file names...